# Looping through all possible ways of having x out of n correct guesses

Tags: loops, math, combinations, probability

I have 10 objects. Each object can be in 3 states, 1, 2, or 3. Let's take the outcome 1111111111. For that one outcome (or any other), I am trying to loop through all the ways one can get 8 out of 10 guesses correct for it. For example, 2111211111 would be one of them. I've managed to get this to work with 9/10 with the loop below, but I need help for getting it to work with 8/10 and 7/10 as well.

For simplicity, let's assume the only combination we're ever checking is 1111111111.

```
    Dim incorrectcombos As New Text.StringBuilder
    For i = 2 To 3
        For j = 0 To 9
            Dim combo As New Text.StringBuilder
            For k = 0 To 9
                If k = j Then
                    combo.Append(i)
                Else
                    combo.Append(1)
                End If
            Next
            incorrectcombos.AppendLine(combo.ToString)
        Next
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(incorrectcombos.ToString)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recursive approach is very simple. Delphi code (note that Delphi string is 1-based)

```
  procedure GenerateCombs(s: string; MaxLen, Position, ErrCount: Integer);
  begin
    if Position = MaxLen + 1 then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s)   //output string
    else begin
      if ErrCount <= MaxLen - Position then  
        GenerateCombs(s + '1', MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount);
      if ErrCount > 0 then begin
        GenerateCombs(s + '2', MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount - 1);
        GenerateCombs(s + '3', MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount - 1);
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  GenerateCombs('', 4, 1, 2);
```

generates

```
1122
1123
1132
1133
1212
1213
1221
1231
1312
1313
1321
1331
2112
2113
2121
2131
2211
2311
3112
3113
3121
3131
3211
3311
```

C# ([ideone](http://ideone.com/8j0oIk)):

```
using System;

public class Test
{
        static public void GenerateCombs(string s, int MaxLen, int Position, int ErrCount) 
        {
          if (Position == MaxLen + 1) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                return;
            }

         if (ErrCount <= MaxLen - Position)
         { 
              GenerateCombs(s + "1", MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount);
         }

          if (ErrCount > 0)
           {
              GenerateCombs(s + "2", MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount - 1);
              GenerateCombs(s + "3", MaxLen, Position + 1, ErrCount - 1);
           } 
        }

    public static void Main()
    {
        GenerateCombs("", 4, 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unsure how to implement this in .net code. It almost works if I don't include the "Begin" line hopping part (except it adds another 1 at the end of every combination). If included, it just loops infinitely over the first part.

Edit: So apparently "Begin" is part of all Delphi procedures. What exactly is meant by "Else begin"?

Comment: `begin .. end == { .. }`

Comment: This worked. Can you think of any non-recursive solutions that are easier to conceptualize and modify? What I'm using it for is a bit more complicated than my example.

Comment: Yes, non-recursive is possible but more complex. You can generate initial strings like `1122, 1123,1133` and apply `next permutation`  algorithm to each.

Comment: Do you have any rough idea of what the code would look like? I was able to build a very slow version that goes over far more combinations than necessary and then discarding duplicates - which is insanely slow.

Comment: As I said, and maybe this is because I'm not used to recursiveness: I find it harder to understand how it works; it feels like I'm putting a black box into the code. Therefore i's difficult for me to modify this from the example to what I'm actually using it for.

Comment: Try to understand - really it is very simple and reflects human method of building result string step-by-step. In any case, I gave clue about "next permutation" algorithm - there is a lot of implementations.